# ng-if should show only one object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi dear Stackoverflow Community i have a problem. First here is my Code:

html:

```
<md-card md-theme-watch flex="100" ng-repeat="offer in company.offers">

    <md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-primary md-fab-oi" aria-label="copy" ng-click="company.setEditVisibility()">

    <oi-offer-edit offer="offer" is-change="true" ng-if="company.isEditVisible">             
    </oi-offer-edit>
</md-card>
```

My controller:

```
function setEditVisibility(){
        vm.isEditVisible = !vm.isEditVisible;
    }
```

it work just fine the problem is that it shows oi-offer-edit directive for every repeated Object.
If you need more info pls dont hesitate to ask!

Comment: All the elements in ng-repeat loop. So do you mean offer-edit is shown for all the repeated elements ? and you want only the clicked element to show up the edit and not the remaining elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to touch your markup and want the `oi-offer-edit` element to be repeated, you have to use a boolean property on the `offer` object itself:

```
<md-card md-theme-watch flex="100" ng-repeat="offer in company.offers">
    <md-button class="..." ng-click="offer.formVisible = !offer.formVisible">

    <oi-offer-edit offer="offer" is-change="true" ng-if="offer.formVisible">             
    </oi-offer-edit>
</md-card>
```

---

*Solution before i realized, that you want to have that directive in every `md-card`:*

You might want to place your `oi-offer-edit` element outside your `ng-repeat` container, because as far as i see it in your snippet, you only need one with the `offer`-data of the selected `company.offers`.

So you could just cache the `offer` on the click handler and make your `oi-offer-edit` visible. Something like this:

```
<md-card md-theme-watch flex="100" ng-repeat="offer in company.offers">
    <md-button class="..." ng-click="company.setEditVisibility(offer)">
</md-card>

<oi-offer-edit offer="currentSelectedOffer" is-change="true" ng-if="company.isEditVisible">             
</oi-offer-edit>

function setEditVisibility(selectedOffer){
     vm.currentSelectedOffer = selectedOffer;
     vm.isEditVisible = !vm.isEditVisible;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry maybe i wasnt clear enough in my Post, every object should have the directive, but only where the button is clicked it should be visiable

Comment: Realized this after my post, but i already edited my answer. I edit it again to make it clearer.

Comment: Wow dude thank you so much your second Walkthrough was the right one you are amazing love you :D. I am stuck for hours now at this Problem

Answer (score 0):

it will because you have bounded to each ng-repeat object .

Comment: I know but how do i define that for every individual object, that it only shows the directive on the object where the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle the visibility of `oi-offer-edit` independently of each offer object then you should move the boolean flag you're checking in the `ng-if` directive into the offers array.

Check the below example it will help you accomplish what you want to do.

```js
angular
   .module('demo', [])
   .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
   
   function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.company = {
      offers: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Offer 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Offer 2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Offer 3' }
      ]
    };
    
    vm.setEditVisibility = setEditVisibility;
    
    function setEditVisibility(id) {
      for (var i = 0; i < vm.company.offers.length; i++) {
        if (vm.company.offers[i].id === id) {
          vm.company.offers[i].isEditVisible = !vm.company.offers[i].isEditVisible;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="offer in ctrl.company.offers">
      {{offer.name}}
      <button ng-click="ctrl.setEditVisibility(offer.id)">Toggle Edit Visibility</button>
      <span ng-if="offer.isEditVisible">{{offer.name}} Edit Details</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```