# Angular 2 change the style of a button onClick

Tags: angular

I am having a lot of trouble trying to update the styling for a button on click.

First, here is the original markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-add" (click)="handleButtonClick(id)">
  Add<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
</button>
```

On clicking the button, I am trying to:

1. Change the class from `"btn btn-add"` to `"btn btn-remove"`
2. Change the `<i class="fa fa-plus-circle">` to `<i class="fa fa-minus-circle">`

How can I do this the angular 2 way?  Right now I just added a boolean and flip that, and show different templates based on the value.  However, it seems there should be a way to handle this through some function right? In the documentation it says you can use strings delimited by a space for multiple classes, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Have you at least tried something? Or took a look at the documentation?

Comment: yeah I looked at the documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html.  It says u can use multiple classes delimited by space but I couldn't get that to work :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your comment you stated, that you tried `ngClass` but had trouble with it:

The directive expects an object with the classname as key and an boolean expression as value. If the expression is true, the class is added, if not it will be removed.

For example your button has the class `btn` and should have either `btn-add` or `btn-remove` depending on a boolean value, than you probably do something like this:

```
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{ 'btn-add': isAddButton, 'btn-remove': !isAddButton  }">
</button>
```

Hope this helps in your understanding of `ngClass`, then it won't be a problem to use it on your other usecases.

Comment: thanks!  but i guess the issue for me is that the buttons are part of an unordered list that shows photos.  is it possible to only change the class for a particular photo that is added?  sorry i am really confused by angualr 2 :(  because now when i add 1 photo, it will change styles for all.

Comment: Well this is a different question :). Without any sample code its hard to give an answer. It's possible of course, for example if you talking about a `ngFor`: instead of using a property of your component, you could use a property of your photo-object directly to decide which class the button should have.

Comment: thx.  i guess i will add that in redux as a flag when clicking add, added = true

Comment: Here's a similar question with an answer from me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439059/ng-if-should-show-only-one-object/39439130#39439130 It's angular1 and about ngClick, but the concept is the same. Basically you iterate over some objects and in your current object you use some sort of flag.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the behavior, visibility or the styling of an element should be driven by the state of your data and it should not alter itself.

Still, if you want to go like this, instead of using a boolean variable as a controller for this kind of functionality, you can pass the event to a function so you can get a reference to the element and it's classlist and manipulate it as you like.

You template should be like that:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="toggleClass($event)">
```

and add this in your class:

```
toggleClass(e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList;
  const classes = e.target.className;
  classes.includes('clicked') ? classList.remove('clicked') : classList.add('clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To toggle the button's text too:

[image]

```
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-add': !clicked, 'btn-remove': clicked}" (click)="clicked = !clicked">
    {{clicked ? 'Remove' : 'Add'}}
    <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-plus-circle': !clicked, 'fa-minus-circle': clicked}"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: I have two buttons like this and i want to select one button at time means only one button want to toggle at time and i can deselect both buttons. Could you please tell me what should i do for this

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:

```
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-add': !clicked, 'btn-remove': clicked}" (click)="clicked = true">
  Add<i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-plus-circle': !clicked, 'fa-minus-circle': clicked}"></i>
</button>
```